# Offset after clipping an image using rasterio.mask (illustrated with figures)

Tags: gdal, clip, rasterio, fiona, masking

I want to clip an image named `img_A` of dimensions 14000x10000 using a polygon shape in order to get the same dimensions than another image named `img_B` of dimensions 1925x1372 **(see figure 1 below)**. The polygon shape has the same extent than `img_B`. Pixel size is 0.1 m for `img_A` and `img_B`.

One important thing is that the pixels of `img_A` are not aligned with the pixels of `img_B` **(figure 2)**. I mean there is a small offset between the pixels of both images (3 cm).

So I used `rasterio.mask` to clip `img_A` and obtain `img_B` extent using that code **(figure 3)**:

```
import fiona
from rasterio.mask import mask

polygon = polygon.shp
raster = img_A.tif
dst = result.tif

with fiona.open(polygon, "r") as shapefile:
    geometry = [feature["geometry"] for feature in shapefile]

with rasterio.open(raster) as src:
    out_image, out_transform = mask(src, geometry, crop=True)
    out_meta = src.meta.copy()
    out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                     "height": out_image.shape[1],
                     "width": out_image.shape[2],
                     "transform": out_transform})

with rasterio.open(dst, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
```

However, the final result is an image of dimensions 1926x1373. Moreover, the new image is slightly offset to the South-West, corresponding to the offset cited previously (3 cm), which means the image is outside of the polygon shape to the West and to the South **(figure 4)**.

How can I obtain a well placed image with dimensions 1925x1372?

**Figure 1 - Input dataset**
[image]

**Figure 2 - Pixel offset**
[image]

**Figure 3 - Overview of the result after clipping**
[image]

**Figure 4 - Problem**
[image]

Comment: Finally, I fixed it using gdal.warp instead of rasterio.mask.